# Scichart TextAnnotation out of main area

Tags: wpf, annotations, scichart

I have 4 `TextAnnotation`s put on the 4 corners of a scichart, like below:

```
<s:TextAnnotation x:Name="topLeftText" HorizontalAnchorPoint="Left" VerticalAnchorPoint="Top"
                                  CoordinateMode="Relative" X1="0" Y1="0"
                                  Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="12"/>
<s:TextAnnotation x:Name="topRightText" HorizontalAnchorPoint="Right" VerticalAnchorPoint="Top"
                                  CoordinateMode="Relative" X1="1" Y1="0"
                                  Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="12">
<s:TextAnnotation x:Name="bottomLeftText" HorizontalAnchorPoint="Left" VerticalAnchorPoint="Bottom"
                                  CoordinateMode="Relative" X1="0" Y1="1"
                                  Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="12">
<s:TextAnnotation x:Name="bottomRightText" HorizontalAnchorPoint="Right" VerticalAnchorPoint="Bottom"
                                  CoordinateMode="Relative" X1="1" Y1="1"
                                  Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="12"/>
```

But sometimes the right 2 `TextAnnotation`s will act weird compared with normal situation (out of main area, see attached picture), can you tell me why?

`TextAnnotation` out of main area:

[image: TextAnnotation out of main area]

`TextAnnotation` normal:

[image: TextAnnotation normal]

I want to know the reason and how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work with the latest version of SciChart WPF. Are you by chance using an old version?

[image]

If you suspect a bug, report it to [the scichart forums](https://www.scichart.com/questions)

Comment: Yes, the version I use is Scichart WPF v6.4.0.13629. I used this version in a simple demo, it acted normal.